# Linear subspace generated by (1,1,1,...,1) in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a linear subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is spanned by a basis vector $(1,1,...,1)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Can $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself be the subsbace? Any help, please? Thanks.

Comment: There is only one subspace spanned by this vector and it consists precisely of all scalar multiples of the vector.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Arguably, the trivial subspace (the subspace consisting only of the origin) is also spanned by the vector.

Comment: How can it span $(1,1...,1)$? It does not even contain this vector. @Acccumulation

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It doesn't span the vector. But depending on the definition of "span", the vector spans it.

Comment: There is only one definition of a space spanned by  a set of vectors. Do not invent your own definitions. @Acccumulation

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all vectors that are generated by $v=(1,1,\cdots,1)$.

In Linear Algebra, **generate** means that this is a combination of the most basic linear operations: addition and multiplication. (by scalars!)

So you  need to find all combinations of multiplications and sums of terms of the form $\lambda\cdot v$.

This is only the set $\{\lambda\cdot v: \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$, i.e a line passsing through $0$ vector. (because 0$\cdot v = 0)$

Answer (score 1):

The subspace is $\{k(1,1,...,1)\ :\ k\in\mathbb R\}$, these vectors are scalar multiples of vector $(1,1,...,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You get a $1$-dimensional space (isomorphic to $\Bbb R$), namely the set of all scalar multiples of $(1,1,\dots,1)$.